# Implementing navigation drawer On the action bar

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

Guys I am implementing the navigation drawer on the action bar
i am getting an error the error is

> 'ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout, android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, int, int)' in 'android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle' cannot be applied to '(com.example.samsung.getstarted.MainActivity, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout, int, int, int)'

my code is

```
private DrawerLayout.DrawerListener createDrawerToggle() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    };
    return mDrawerToggle;
}
```

please help me in solving this

Comment: Extend ActionBarActivity or FragmentActivity not Activity

Comment: please share your MainActivity

Comment: That means your params are all messed up. Pass your toolbar where you passed the drawable

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using a different version of DrawerLayout.
Delete the

```
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
```

android import again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this line code:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) 
{
}
```

you have import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`, so you should use constructor as:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes) 

or 

ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

So for your case, just remove `R.drawable.ic_drawer` from your instantiation.

Otherwise you could change the import for `ActionBarDrawerToggle` with V4, but it is already deprecated.

Hope this help!